# Google App Script MailApp stopped sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script

My first Google App Script test wasn't a success as I got my MailApp into a loop for sending test emails to my own email address. The if expression was faulty which resulted to sending emails from every row with range E:E, meaning the script went through to the if clause to send an email from each row of the referred sheet. I stopped the script of course as I noticed the problem but a couple of hundreds of test emails got sent before cancellation. After this, the same script wont send any email. Have I been placed on black list as a spam man?

[google-apps-script]

Comment: Could be. Can you show your script?

Answer (score 2):

You have likely exceeded the daily email send quota.  You can verify this with `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getremainingdailyquota)).  If it is 0, you'll have to wait until tomorrow to send again.  But no, you haven't been blacklisted.

[See here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for a list of quotas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I got the script working by changing the email address to where it sends the email. So, apparently my daily quota wasn't exceeded as I managed to get it working on the same day. Anyhow, now everything is in order and it works like a charm. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Just for clearifying purposes:

> Script worked by changing the email address to where it sends the email. So, apparently my daily quota wasn't exceeded.